# Swift how to init Date

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create model object which has `Date` but I can't find out how to `init` in terms of converting to `String`.

This is the date structure.

```
let date = NSDate()
let format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM/dd HH:mm"
let strDate = format.string(from: date as Date)
```

Model

```
import UIKit

    struct Post {

        var Date: Date!
        var Text: String

        init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
            self.Date = dictionary["Date"] as? Date
            self.Text = dictionary["Text"] as? String ?? ""
        }
    }
```

After I fetch data from firebase, I would like to do like below but error says

> Cannot assign value of type 'Date.Type' to type 'String?'

```
var post: Post? {
        didSet {

            dateLabel.text = post?.Date
            caprionLabel.text = post?.Text
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how can I fix this? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need convert from post?.Date to String

Comment: you can't set the date as string on label.text. first you change date into string. You Can try this extension

 extension Date
{
    func toString( dateFormat format  : String ) -> String
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }

}

Use:
let today = Date()
today.toString(dateFormat: "Your desire format")// dd-MM

Comment: You already posted date formatter code that converts a `Date` object to a string at the top of your question. Use that code to convert your `Date` to a `String`.

Comment: @DuncanC how would you do that? I did like so `let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM/dd HH:mm"
            guard let date = post?.Date else { return }
            let str = formatter.string(from: date)
            dataLabel.text = str` but `dataLabel.text` returns nothing. How should I fix this?

Comment: It's impossible to know what you did from a comment. Edit your question to show the code you tried, and the result you are getting.

Comment: @DuncanC thank you for the comment but I finally figured it out. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused with **Date** and **String**, both are different Objects, You can't assign to each other.

There are two solutions to the same

1. If you want to show exactly the same date that is coming,

   ```
   import UIKit

   struct Post {

   var dateString:String!
   var Text: String

   init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
       self.dateString = dictionary["Date"] as? String
       self.Text = dictionary["Text"] as? String ?? ""
   }
   }
   ```

   ALSO , Label can only Accept String to save

   ```
     var post: Post? {
       didSet {

           dateLabel.text = post?.dateString
           caprionLabel.text = post?.Text
       }
   }
   ```
2. Save both Date and String in your model

   ```
    struct Post {


       var dateString:String!
       var date:Date!
       var Text: String

       init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {

         self.dateString = dictionary["Date"] as? String
         let format = DateFormatter()
         format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM/dd HH:mm"

    // If dateString doesn't match your date Format Provided

          self.date = format.date(from: dateString) ?? Date()
           self.Text = dictionary["Text"] as? String ?? ""
       }
   }
   ```

   ALSO , Label can only Accept String to save

   ```
     var post: Post? {
       didSet {
     let format = DateFormatter()

    // Assign to any format you want
    format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM/dd HH:mm"
    dateLabel.text = format.string(from: post!.date)

           caprionLabel.text = post?.Text
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because `Date` (uppercase) is a reserved struct type in Swift. The error message

> Cannot assign value of type 'Date.**Type**' to type 'String?'

clearly states it.

---

**Conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter**. It avoids this kind of silly type errors.

And **never ever** declare variables in a struct as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized in an `init` method. If they are supposed to be optional declare them as regular optional (`?`).

And put the code to format the date as string in the struct.

```
import UIKit

    struct Post {

        var date: Date?
        var text: String

        init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
            self.date = dictionary["Date"] as? Date
            self.text = dictionary["Text"] as? String ?? ""
        }

        var formattedDate : String {
           let format = DateFormatter()
           format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM/dd HH:mm"
           return format.string(from: date)
        }
    }
```

---

```
var post: Post? {
    didSet {
        dateLabel.text = post?.formattedDate
        caprionLabel.text = post?.text
    }
}
```